# Create an ArrayList of unique values

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` with values taken from a file (many lines, this is just an extract):

```
20/03/2013 23:31:46 6870    6810    6800    6720    6860    6670    6700    6650    6750    6830    34864   34272
20/03/2013 23:31:46 6910    6780    6800    6720    6860    6680    6620    6690    6760    6790    35072   34496
```

Where the first two values per line are strings that contain data and are stored in a single element.

What I want to do is compare the string data elements and delete, for example, the second one and all the elements referred to in that line.

For now, I've used a `for` loop that compares the string every 13 elements (in order to compare only data strings).

My question: can I implement other better solutions?

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        //The input file
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("prova.txt"));

        //Saving each element of the input file in an arraylist 
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (s.hasNext()){
            list.add(s.next());
        }
        s.close();

        //Arraylist to save modified values
        ArrayList<String> ds = new ArrayList<String>();

        //
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<=list.size()-13; i=i+14){

            //combining the first to values to obtain data  
            String str = list.get(i)+" "+list.get(i+1);
            ds.add(str);
            //add all the other values to arraylist ds
            int j;
            for(j=2; j<14; j++){
                ds.add(list.get(i+j));
            }

            //comparing data values
            int k;  
            for(k=0; k<=ds.size()-12; k=k+13){
                ds.get(k); //first data string element  
                //Comparing with other strings and delete
                //TODO  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post your question here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Code is not completed 1 braces is missing so please post complte code

Comment: @AshishAggarwal, now should be ok although the comparing values part isn't not implemented at all

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> Create an Arraylist of unique values

You could use `Set.toArray()` method.

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets
>   contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at
>   most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models
>   the mathematical set abstraction.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: Ok, but how i can do to delete all the values related to the data string? I mean, if i find a data string equal to another, i must delete all the values related to this

Comment: `Set.toArray()` doesn't keep the elements order. Is there a way to keep the order?

Comment: @italo Why -1? please explain

Comment: An ArrayList keep the elements order, Set doesn't. An ArrayList of unique values is not the same of transforming a Set to an ArrayList. I came to this question looking for an ArrayList of unique values and I didn't find it yet.

Comment: Complementing... Looking for a good/smart implementation for an ArrayList of unique values.

Comment: @italo you could potentially use LinkedHashSet: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html which will retain the insertion order. Depends on what order you wish to maintain for duplicates.

Answer (score 76):

Try checking for duplicates with a `.contains()` method on the ArrayList, before adding a new element.

It would look something like this

```
   if(!list.contains(data))
       list.add(data);
```

That should **prevent duplicates in the list, as well as not mess up the order of elements**, like people seem to look for.

Comment: This will work but don't forget to make this synchronized, otherwise you asking for trouble

Comment: Does this affect performance if it has large data? I think it will.

Comment: @Amt87 It is a membership test. Should be a O(log n) call at most. If you would like to retain the order of the elements, I don't think we can best it.

Comment: As @Amt87 mentioned performance will be affected for large data. Membership test in a regular ArrayList is O(n), not O(log n). So you are looking at O(n^2) when you are populating the list.

Answer (score 19):

```
HashSet hs = new HashSet();
                hs.addAll(arrayList);
                arrayList.clear();
                arrayList.addAll(hs);
```

Comment: This provides unique records as in the question but if you need to keep the order of the data this will not work.

Answer (score 17):

Pretty late to the party, but here's my two cents:

## Use a [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)

I assume what you need is a collection which:

- disallows you to insert duplicates;
- retains insertion order.

`LinkedHashSet` does this. The advantage over using an `ArrayList` is that `LinkedHashSet` has a complexity of *O(1)* for the `contains` operation, as opposed to `ArrayList`, which has *O(n)*.

---

<sup>Of course, you need to implement your object's `equals` and `hashCode` methods properly.</sup>

Comment: Very underrated answer !

Comment: Much simpler solution that additionally using contains, major +1

Answer (score 8):

If you want to make a list with unique values from an existing list you can use

```
List myUniqueList = myList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is the third time this exact snippet is posted as a solution...

Answer (score 6):

```
 //Saving each element of the input file in an arraylist 
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (s.hasNext()){
        list.add(s.next());
    }

//That's all you need
list = (ArrayList) list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It is working from api level 24. doesn't support below versions

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do this with a `Hashmap`. You obviously have a key (which is the String data) and some values.

Loop on all your lines and add them to your Map.

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
...
while (s.hasNext()){
  String stringData = ...
  List<Integer> values = ...
  map.put(stringData,values);
}
```

Note that in this case, you will keep the **last** occurence of duplicate lines. If you prefer keeping the **first** occurence and removing the others, you can add a check with `Map.containsKey(String stringData);` before putting in the map.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Set`

```
      ...
      Set<String> list = new HashSet<>();
      while (s.hasNext()){
         list.add(s.next());
      }
      ...
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Solution #1: `HashSet`

A good solution to the immediate problem of reading a file into an `ArrayList` with a uniqueness constraint is to simply keep a [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) of seen items. Before processing a line, we check that its key is not already in the set. If it isn't, we add the key to the set to mark it as finished, then add the line data to the result `ArrayList`.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        String file = "prova.txt";
        ArrayList<String[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
        HashSet<String> seen = new HashSet<>();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
                String[] split = line.split("\\s+");
                String key = split[0] + " " + split[1];

                if (!seen.contains(key)) {
                    data.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(split, 2, split.length));
                    seen.add(key);
                }
            }
        }

        for (String[] row : data) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Solution #2: `LinkedHashMap`/`LinkedHashSet`

Since we have key-value pairs in this particular dataset, we could roll everything into a `LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` ([see docs for `LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)) which preserves ordering but can't be indexed into (use-case driven decision, but amounts to the same strategy as above. `ArrayList<String>` or `String[]` is arbitrary here--it could be any data value). Note that this version makes it easy to preserve the most recently seen key rather than the oldest (remove the `!data.containsKey(key)` test).

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        String file = "prova.txt";
        LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> data = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
                String[] split = line.split("\\s+");
                String key = split[0] + " " + split[1];

                if (!data.containsKey(key)) {
                    ArrayList<String> val = new ArrayList<>();
                    String[] sub = Arrays.copyOfRange(split, 2, split.length); 
                    Collections.addAll(val, sub);
                    data.put(key, val);
                }
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> e : data.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + " => " + e.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Solution #3: `ArrayListSet`

The above examples represent pretty narrow use cases. Here's a sketch for a general `ArrayListSet` class, which maintains the usual list behavior (`add`/`set`/`remove` etc) while preserving uniqueness.

Basically, the class is an abstraction of solution #1 in this post (`HashSet` combined with `ArrayList`), but with a slightly different flavor (the data itself is used to determine uniqueness rather than a key, but it's a truer "`ArrayList`" structure).

This class solves the problems of efficiency (`ArrayList#contains` is linear, so we should reject that solution except in trivial cases), lack of ordering (storing everything directly in a `HashSet` doesn't help us), lack of `ArrayList` operations ([`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) is otherwise the best solution but we can't index into it, so it's not a true replacement for an `ArrayList`).

Using a `HashMap<E, index>` instead of a `HashSet` would speed up `remove(Object o)` and `indexOf(Object o)` functions (but slow down `sort`). A linear `remove(Object o)` is the main drawback over a plain `HashSet`.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayListSet<E> implements Iterable<E>, Set<E> {
    private ArrayList<E> list;
    private HashSet<E> set;

    public ArrayListSet() {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        set = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public boolean add(E e) {
        return set.add(e) && list.add(e);
    }

    public boolean add(int i, E e) {
        if (!set.add(e)) return false;
        list.add(i, e);
        return true;
    }

    public void clear() {
        list.clear();
        set.clear();
    }

    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return set.contains(o);
    }

    public E get(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return list.isEmpty();
    }

    public E remove(int i) {        
        E e = list.remove(i);
        set.remove(e);
        return e;
    }

    public boolean remove(Object o) {        
        if (set.remove(o)) {
            list.remove(o);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean set(int i, E e) {
        if (set.contains(e)) return false;

        set.add(e);
        set.remove(list.set(i, e));
        return true;
    }

    public int size() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public void sort(Comparator<? super E> c) {
        Collections.sort(list, c);
    }

    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return list.iterator();
    }

    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        int before = size();
        for (E e : c) add(e);
        return size() == before;
    }

    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return set.containsAll(c);
    }

    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return set.removeAll(c) && list.removeAll(c);
    }

    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
         return set.retainAll(c) && list.retainAll(c);
    }

    public Object[] toArray() {
        return list.toArray();
    }

    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        return list.toArray(a);
    }
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
public class ArrayListSetDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayListSet<String> fruit = new ArrayListSet<>();
        fruit.add("apple");
        fruit.add("banana");
        fruit.add("kiwi");
        fruit.add("strawberry");
        fruit.add("apple");
        fruit.add("strawberry");

        for (String item : fruit) {
            System.out.print(item + " "); // => apple banana kiwi strawberry
        }

        fruit.remove("kiwi");
        fruit.remove(1);
        fruit.add(0, "banana");
        fruit.set(2, "cranberry");
        fruit.set(0, "cranberry");
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < fruit.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(fruit.get(i) + " "); // => banana apple cranberry
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

---

#### Solution #4: `ArrayListMap`

This class solves a drawback of `ArrayListSet` which is that the data we want to store and its associated key may not be the same. This class provides a `put` method that enforces uniqueness on a different object than the data stored in the underlying `ArrayList`. This is just what we need to solve the original problem posed in this thread. This gives us the ordering and iteration of an `ArrayList` but fast lookups and uniqueness properties of a `HashMap`. The `HashMap` contains the unique values mapped to their index locations in the `ArrayList`, which enforces ordering and provides iteration.

This approach solves the scalability problems of using a `HashSet` in solution #1. That approach works fine for a quick file read, but without an abstraction, we'd have to handle all consistency operations by hand and pass around multiple raw data structures if we needed to enforce that contract across multiple functions and over time.

As with `ArrayListSet`, this can be considered a proof of concept rather than a full implementation.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayListMap<K, V> implements Iterable<V>, Map<K, V> {
    private ArrayList<V> list;
    private HashMap<K, Integer> map;

    public ArrayListMap() {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        map = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void clear() {
        list.clear();
        map.clear();
    }

    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return map.containsKey(key);
    }

    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        return list.contains(value);
    }

    public V get(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return map.isEmpty();
    }

    public V get(Object key) {
        return list.get(map.get(key));
    }

    public V put(K key, V value) {
        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            int i = map.get(key);
            V v = list.get(i);
            list.set(i, value);
            return v;
        }

        list.add(value);
        map.put(key, list.size() - 1);
        return null;
    }

    public V putIfAbsent(K key, V value) {
        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            if (list.get(map.get(key)) == null) {
                list.set(map.get(key), value);
                return null;
            }

            return list.get(map.get(key));
        }

        return put(key, value);
    }

    public V remove(int i) {
        V v = list.remove(i);

        for (Map.Entry<K, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue() == i) {
                map.remove(entry.getKey());
                break;
            }
        }

        decrementMapIndices(i);
        return v;
    }

    public V remove(Object key) {
        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            int i = map.remove(key);
            V v = list.get(i);
            list.remove(i);
            decrementMapIndices(i);
            return v;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void decrementMapIndices(int start) {
        for (Map.Entry<K, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            int i = entry.getValue();

            if (i > start) {
                map.put(entry.getKey(), i - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        for (Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> entry : m.entrySet()) {
            put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    public Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> es = new HashSet<>();

        for (Map.Entry<K, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            es.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
                entry.getKey(), list.get(entry.getValue())
            ));
        }

        return es;
    }

    public Set<K> keySet() {
        return map.keySet();
    }

    public Collection<V> values() {
        return list;
    }

    public Iterator<V> iterator() {
        return list.iterator();
    }

    public Object[] toArray() {
        return list.toArray();
    }

    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        return list.toArray(a);
    }
}
```

Here's the class in action on the original problem:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        String file = "prova.txt";
        ArrayListMap<String, String[]> data = new ArrayListMap<>();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
                String[] split = line.split("\\s+");
                String key = split[0] + " " + split[1];
                String[] sub = Arrays.copyOfRange(split, 2, split.length); 
                data.putIfAbsent(key, sub); 
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> e : data.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + " => " + 
                java.util.Arrays.toString(e.getValue()));
        }

        for (String[] a : data) {
            System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(a));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a Set. It is a collection which doesn't accept duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Just Override the boolean equals() method of custom object. Say you have an ArrayList with custom field f1, f2, ... override

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof CustomObject)) return false;

    CustomObject object = (CustomObject) o;

    if (!f1.equals(object.dob)) return false;
    if (!f2.equals(object.fullName)) return false;
    ...
    return true;
}
```

and check using ArrayList instance's contains() method. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need unique values, you should use the implementation of the `SET` interface

Comment: Set is not accessed by INDEX. Not the same!

Answer (score 0):

You can read from file to map, where the key is the date and skip if the the whole row if the date is already in map

```
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        int i = 0;
        String lastData = null;
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            String str = s.next();
            if (i % 13 == 0) {
                if (map.containsKey(str)) {
                    //skip the whole row
                    lastData = null;
                } else {
                    lastData = str;
                    map.put(lastData, new ArrayList<String>());
                }
            } else if (lastData != null) {
                map.get(lastData).add(str);
            }


            i++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use helper class. Not sure it's good or bad

```
public class ListHelper<T> {
    private final T[] t;

    public ListHelper(T[] t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public List<T> unique(List<T> list) {
       Set<T> set = new HashSet<>(list);
        return Arrays.asList(set.toArray(t));
    }
}
```

---

Usage and test:

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;


public class ListHelperTest {

    @Test
    public void unique() {
        List<String> s = Arrays.asList("abc", "cde", "dfg", "abc");
        List<String> unique = new ListHelper<>(new String[0]).unique(s);
        assertThat(unique).hasSize(3);
    }
}
```

Or Java8 version:

```
public class ListHelper<T> {
    public Function<List<T>, List<T>> unique() {
        return l -> l.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

public class ListHelperTest {
    @Test
    public void unique() {
        List<String> s = Arrays.asList("abc", "cde", "dfg", "abc");
        assertThat(new ListHelper<String>().unique().apply(s)).hasSize(3);
    }
}
```