# How to have a ArrayList with a unique ID

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, static

i created an Arraylist of Student objects. i am using a static variable as an ID.

this is what my Student class looks like;

---

[Student class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtqYf.jpg)

---

And the Runner file looks like;

[Runner file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmJL7.jpg)

---

---

the output i receive is;

St_ID    St_Name     St_Age      St_Course 
3   James       23      Statistics
3   Mick        24      Biology
3   Jenni       22      Literature

but what i require is;

St_ID    St_Name     St_Age      St_Course 
1   James       23      Statistics
2   Mick        24      Biology
3   Jenni       22      Literature

Comment: Don't use a static value - or, reassign the running value to a non-static variable, so you would have a "generator" which would generate the next value, but that value need to be assigned to an instance field of your class

Comment: Please do NOT post pictures of code, include the code directly.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: Follow the link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547360/create-an-arraylist-of-unique-values

Comment: Do the ids have to be starting from 1 and counting up? Because if you call hashcode() on your student class instances it will give you a unique number to identify your students by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the `count` variable being static. However, the `Student` class should also have a field that stores the id of *each* student. This should be non-static since each student is going to have a different one.

```
private int id;
```

In the constructor, assign `count` to it:

```
count++;
id = count;
```

The `getId` method should be non-static and return `id`:

```
public int getId() { return id; }
```

Comment: Thank you Sweeper, finally got it working, i appreciate your help.

Comment: @ThivankaW if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark!

Answer (score 0):

If all you cant is a unique id, calling stobj.hashCode() will return a unique hashcode, so each student has a unique id. However, if you need the ids to start at 1 and count up, then keep the count, but also make a non-static variable and set it equal to the current count in the constructor.

```
public class Student {
    //fields here
    private static int count = 0; //not good style, but whatever
    private int id;

    public Student(String n, int a, String c) //you should work on your variable names
        count++;
        id = count;
        //other stuff here
```

Comment: Thank you so much Meepo, it worked. thanks for the constructive answer.